# Wording of "at least [n] reputation points to post images" is misleading

Tags: bug, new-users, privileges, images

I wanted to post a picture with my question on Stack Overflow, but an error message came up saying "You need at least 10 reputation points to post images" yet I have exactly 10 rep.

Is this a bug or am I misinterpreting the error message?

It says "at least" therefore doesn't that mean my rep has to be >= 10? not >10?

Comment: It needs to be 11 or more, yes.

Comment: @Sha - No. As per [privilege page](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/new-user) you need 10 reputation to post image.

Comment: Actually you have to gain 10 reps after starting with the default 1.

Comment: @hims056 agree it's misleading, but I strongly believe that for all privileges you need **more** than the required reputation, e.g. 11 for  new user restrictions.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Really confusion. I could see tools when I reached exact 10000 on meta (AFAIK)

Comment: @hims056 so maybe only for that privilege. Balpha ignored it smoothly so guess it's not a bug.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd wow that other question is not "Status Completed" at all then... replacing "at least" with "over/more than" would actually fix.

Comment: @hayd yeah, Jeff had (has?) a weird way of saying "that's not a bug".

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd "I strongly believe that for all privileges you need more than the required reputation" That's a totally absurd way for things to work, though my experience leads me to think that statement isn't correct anyway. Regardless of what Jeff said, that *is* a bug and *something* needs changing.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist just saying what it appears to behave like from experience and seeing reports here on Meta. Like I said before maybe it happens only for that specific privilege.

Comment: It's not "misleading", it's "incorrect".